# Value 4 when computing primes using Fermat's Little Theorem

Tags: python, python-2.7, math

I wrote a program which is not important now, but it was on this Fermat's theorem. Now the problem is the output was not as expected. I know the question is not too good or off the mark but I just can't solve the error which is that there is an occurrence of 4 here in the output which must not be there. I'm unable to debug it.

The theorem: [image: This Image]

```
for x in range(1,100):
 m=5**(x-1)
 if m%x>1:    
   pass
 else:
   print"prime",x
```

Output is this:

[image: This is output]

Comment: *output was not as expected*, What was the expected output? Additionally. Please don't post images as code, [See this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3933332). Also see [ask] and what is a [mcve]

Comment: @bhargav-rao the output would not include 4 (see image attached )but it has since the theorem isn't wrong so there must be error somewhere

Comment: Kindly [edit] your post and add the description of your error there.

Comment: @Bhargav Rao Added

Comment: Add it _as text_.

Comment: also note that a `p` which passes the test is not necessarily prime; all the theorem states is that a `p` which does not pass the test is not prime.

Comment: `print "prime",x` is a mathematical miunderstanding. FLT provides a sufficient test for compositeness, not a sufficient test for primality (although it does provide a necessary test for primality).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A perfect explanation is found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29596459/5110035

Basically this method is not very accurate.
I found a pattern in your code. If `a` is chosen 5, then `a-1` non-prime is printed. That's why 4 comes up. Change it to 7 and you get 6. But also other errors come up such as 25.

Fermat's Little Theorem can be easily written in Python like this:

`def CheckIfProbablyPrime(x):
    return pow(2, x-1, x) == 1`

The only reason why I think four comes up is because of your algorithm being a bit incorrect. Sieve of Eratosthenes, once it finds a non-prime it then gets rid of its multiples such as 4 is a multiple of 2 but 2 is prime as 4 is not. It checks less numbers and much faster. Look into that.

Comment: In `CheckIfProbablyPrime` better test multiple small primes, for example randomly pick the four primes 2,5,11,23, this should catch most of the false positives up to mediums sized numbers. Perform test with prime `p` only if `x>p`.