# How do I optimize my Python code to perform my calculation using less memory?

Tags: python, math, optimization, numbers

I have put together the following code in order to determine if a number has an odd or even number of divisors. The code works well with relatively small numbers but once a larger number like 9 digits is entered it hangs up.

```
def divisors(n):
    num = len(set([x for x in range(1,n+1) if not divmod(n,x)[1]]))
    if (num != 0 and num % 2 == 0):
        return 'even'
    else:
        return 'odd'
```

what can I do to make this more efficient?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171765/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-all-the-divisors-of-a-number or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421969/finding-all-divisors-of-a-number-optimization

Answer (score 2):

Here's your problem:

```
num = len(set([x for x in range(1,n+1) if not divmod(n,x)[1]]))
```

This constructs a list, then constructs a set out of that list, then takes the length of the set.  You don't need to do any of that work (`range()`, or `xrange()` for that matter, does not produce repeated objects, so we don't need the set, and `sum()` works on any iterable object, so you don't need the list either).  While we're on the subject, `divmod(n, x)[1]` is just a very elaborate way of writing `n % x`, and consumes a little bit of extra memory to construct a tuple (which is immediately reclaimed because you throw the tuple away).  Here's the fixed version:

```
num = sum(1 for x in xrange(1,n+1) if not n % x)
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to test every possible divisor, testing up to sqrt(n) is enough. This will make your function O(sqrt(n)) instead of O(n).

```
import math

def num_divisors(n):
    sqrt = math.sqrt(n)
    upper = int(sqrt)
    num = sum(1 for x in range(1, upper + 1) if not n % x)
    num *= 2
    if upper == sqrt and num != 0:
        num -= 1
    return num
```

In my benchmarks using python2 this is 1000 times faster than `sum(1 for x in range(1, n + 1) if not n % x)` with `n = int(1e6)` and 10000 times faster for 1e8. For `1e9` the latter code gave me a memory error<s>, suggesting that the whole sequence is stored in memory before doing the sum</s> because in python 2 `range()` returns a list and I should be using `xrange()` instead. For python3 `range()` is fine.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me to use `xrange()` instead of `range()`.